# EntityManagerFactory singleton on multi thread

Tags: multithreading, maven, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I have an application (javaee / wildfly / Maven) who works like that :
Thread processA (trigger Thread  processB in background)

I'm using Stateless EJB with @PersistenceContext everything is working fine in the processA, my issue is on the processB the entity persisted inside processA are not up to date in processB, I assume it's because @PersistenceContext has a cache on each process is it right ?
So first I wanted to find a way to "refresh" the cache when the only method I used in processB is called, but I don't find anything to do that ...

Then after more readings I discover that the EntityManager is not thread safe and it's better to use a @singleton with an EntityManagerFactory created only once because it's expensive like here :
https://subhadipsblog.wordpress.com/2017/09/16/correct-way-of-using-entitymanager-in-singleton-ejb/

```
@Singleton
public class PersistenceService
{
 @PersistenceUnit(name="somePU")
 EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

And creating EntityManager as below:

```
public void persistenceMethod(Entity myEntity)
{
 EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
 ... //Persistence operations
 em.close();
}
```

EDIT :
So I've added this :

```
@Singleton
public class PersistenceService {

    @PersistenceUnit(name="MyPu")
    EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public ImportState createEntity(MyEntity myEntity) {

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.merge(myEntity);
        em.close();
        }

    public List<MyEntity> getMyEntities() {

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        List<MyEntity> myEntities = em.createQuery("from MyEntity as myEntity, MyEntity.class)
                .getResultList();
        em.close();
        return myEntities;
    }
}
```

And in my services :

```
@EJB PersistenceService persistenceService;
```

But I still have the same issue ...

- ThreadA -> persistenceService.createEntity(myEntity) -> entity is created in Database (org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl@3097af5)
- ThreadB -> persistenceService.getMyEntities() -> entity created by ThreadA is not seen (org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl@3097af5)

EDIT threadB creation :

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("debut tache " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                try {
                    System.err.println(persistenceService.getMyEntities());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("fin tache");
            }
        });
```

Comment: ThreadB will take the data from DB. Do you ever commit a transaction that inserts myEntity in ThreadA?

Comment: When I was using Stateless EJB with @PersistenceContext commit was automatic, so no I don't commit transaction and even if I add  em.getTransaction().commit(); before closing the em I have "A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction" error and em.flush() doesn't change anything / The entity (Thread A) is created in the database I've checked it

Comment: How are you creating the "Thread processB"? Which version of WildFly are you using?

Comment: Wildfly 10, I've added the code regarding the creation of Thread processB

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because your thread does not have the correct contexts setup. You'd need to copy the contexts, which *may* be rather cumbersome. If you want to create threads you should use the [Java EE Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/concurrency-utilities.htm) utilities.